# How to fix <select> dropdown shaking horizontally (Firefox only)?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, firefox, html-select

Has anyone found a fix for  dropdowns shaking horizontally at a rapid rate in Firefox only? Comments of others that have seen this but not found a fix would be appreciated also.

[image: aligned select dropdown]

[image: misaligned select dropdown]

HTML code: (It still does it even after the list has populated)

```html
<select class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="batchStatus" name="batchStatus" style="font-size: 14px;" ng-model="lineStatus" ng-options="value.listCode as value.listDesc for value in batchStatus">
  <option class="" value="">Select Status ...</option>
</select>
```

Computed CSS Code for select tag: (There are too many css styles to post)

```css
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #444;
cursor: default;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Helvetica,Arial,"Nimbus Sans L",sans-serif;
font-feature-settings: normal;
font-kerning: auto;
font-language-override: normal;
font-size: 14px;
font-size-adjust: none;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-synthesis: weight style;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-alternates: normal;
font-variant-caps: normal;
font-variant-east-asian: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-variant-position: normal;
font-weight: 500;
height: 23px;
line-height: 17.9px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
width: 180px;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Computed CSS Code for option tag:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #000;
cursor: default;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Helvetica,Arial,"Nimbus Sans L",sans-serif;
font-feature-settings: normal;
font-kerning: auto;
font-language-override: normal;
font-size: 14px;
font-size-adjust: none;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-synthesis: weight style;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-alternates: normal;
font-variant-caps: normal;
font-variant-east-asian: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-variant-position: normal;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 17.9px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
```

Note: I have tried searching for answers. [A firefox addon was the issue](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/671923) was the closest thing I could find. But I tried disabling all the addons as it suggested with no luck. 
I tagged AngularJS, but doubt that is the issue, especially since the issues remains even when nothing has loaded.

Comment: I tried creating a Plunker but couldn't replicate it so didn't post it. Then again if I could replicate it, I probably could have solved the issue.

Comment: We'd need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As you said: without it, it's almost impossible to know what's going on

Comment: Does the problem occur for you on your computer in this snippet here?

Comment: @MrLister, No only in dev environment. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

My co-worker and I solved the issue with a hack that forced the vertical scrollbar to show even when the pages content would not push below the fold.

```
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/

I am guessing substituting ng-if for ng-show might be another solution.

**Problem Details**

The problem was a combination of using angularJS's **ng-show**, ui-grid's attribute **ui-grid-selection** and having short pages that ended **above the fold**.

The weirdest thing is that without the ui-grid's ui-grid-selection attribute it worked fine. Must be a CSS issue(maybe positioning) where the ui-grids selection adds height even if it is not visible (ng-show, display: none;).

Note: Using AngularJS 1.2.28 and ui-grid 3.0.0-RC20.

Comment: Although I wasn't able to measure the offset of the options dropdown because it was continuously jumping back and forth, it appears to be off by the same width as the scrollbar. (~18px)